# How to insert the image at the specified position in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I searched StackOverflow but I didn't find any opted solution. I have `ListView`, and I want to delete(like swipe the listview item) the listview item and replace with new image at that position in `ListView`, how to do that?

Comment: Is this a ListView of images and you want to add an additional image at a specified index? Or do you have a ListView of something else and want an image at a specified index?

Comment: @atomicrat2552 already i have something in my listview(position) i want to replace that with my image.

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples. Check this one out. [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html)

Your listitem xml file should have the ImageView and this should be populated in GetView function.

Or if you need the Imageview only for a particular position say position 10, then in GetView function, check for that position 10, and inflate a seperate layout which has ImageView in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect URL for your solution

http://expertnotfound.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/customizing-the-android-listview/

Check it and implement according to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a custom listview and also a separate file for the listview Items in your layout folder `(say listview_items.xml)`, and in this file keep `relative layout` as your root layout and then you will be able to move your imageview at any specified position freely.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To replace an item in your `ListView`, you need to change the data in the backing `Adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the `Adapter`.

Depending on what you're doing, you may also need to subclass one of the `Adapter` classes (I usually subclass `BaseAdapter`) and do custom logic in `getView` to handle deciding what layout to inflate. Make sure to use `ViewHolder` pattern so that you're not re-inflating views that aren't changing.

Hope that helps!